# Find all solutions to integral equation

Tags: analysis, integral-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given functions such that $\int_\mathbb{R} F(x) dx = 0$.
>
> Find all $h:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying 
>   \begin{align}
> \int_\mathbb{R} h(x,y)f(x,y) dy &= F(x) \\
> \int_\mathbb{R} h(x,y)f(x,y) dx &= 0  \qquad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
> \end{align}

Can you please point me in the direction how tackle this kind of problem?

I don't even know if such $h$ exists. But I have felling that it exists but it is not unique, so is there an easy way how to characterize all the solutions?

Comment: Important question: are you working with continuous functions, or $L^2$ functions, $L^1$ functions...?

Comment: Well I have no strict requirements on those functions. They probably have to be $L^2$ to make sense of those integrals. But you can assume that they are continuous if you want to.

Comment: Well, maybe some continuous $h$ does not exist, while some non continuous $h$ exists, so there is quite big difference between considering non-continuous functions or not. For example, if $f,h \in L^2$, then $F$ must be continuous. So your problem has no solution if $F$ is a given non-continuous function.

Comment: Consider it as part of the problem, for given $f,F$ is there such $h$? and how nice the $h$ is?

Comment: Why $F$ has to be continuous, when $f,h \in L^2$?